# Join two bounding boxes bboxes

Tags: javascript, gis, mapbox, turfjs

I have two bounding boxes and want to create a big one that includes this 2 - join them.

For example(2 results of the turf.bbox):

```
  var bboxCircles = turf.bbox({
            "type": "FeatureCollection",
            "name": "bboxes",
            "features": circles
          });

          var bboxPoly = turf.bbox({
            "type": "FeatureCollection",
            "name": "bboxes",
            "features": polygon
          });

        bboxCircles = [10, 5, 15, 12];
        bboxPoly = [-35.9999999999999, -18.9999999999999, 35.4250000000001, 45.5000000000001];

var resBbox = bboxCircles.concat(bboxPoly).reduce(function(result, value, index, array) {
        if (index % 2 === 0)
          result.push(array.slice(index, index + 2));
        return result;
      }, []);

      var bounds = new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds();
      resBbox.forEach(item => {
          bounds.extend(item);
      });
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Is there an easy way with turf etc.? 
thanks

Comment: @NewToJS added my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this could be solved using a combination of `bboxPolygon`, `combine` and `bbox`. `bboxPolygon` converts a bounding box to a Polygon feature.

```
var resBbox = turf.bbox(turf.bboxPolygon(bboxCircles).combine(turf.bboxPolygon(bboxPoly)));
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks ok. But with this var fc = turf.featureCollection([
  turf.bboxPolygon(bboxCircles),
 turf.bboxPolygon(bboxPoly),
]);

var combined = turf.combine(fc);  https://jsfiddle.net/fcronv64/

Answer (score 3):

There is also a quite easy way without any libraries like Turf (Typescript example):

```js
type BBox = [number, number, number, number];

const mergeBoundingBoxes = (boundingBoxes: BBox[]): BBox => {
  let minLeft: number = 180;
  let minBottom: number = 90;
  let maxRight: number = -180;
  let maxTop: number = -90;

  boundingBoxes.forEach(([left, bottom, right, top]) => {
    if (left < minLeft) minLeft = left;
    if (bottom < minBottom) minBottom = bottom;
    if (right > maxRight) maxRight = right;
    if (top > maxTop) maxTop = top;
  });

  return [minLeft, minBottom, maxRight, maxTop];
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative

```js
turf.bbox(turf.union(turf.bboxPolygon(bbox1), turf.bboxPolygon(bbox2)))
```